# Pull Specific Video Views From A Particular Time Range - YouTube Data API v3

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm looking for a way to pull video view stats for the past month into a Google Sheet using a script and YouTube's API. I'm able to get the lifetime view count, but is there a way to get the view count for a specific time range?

I don't see any documentation that this is possible on YouTube's API, but I figured I'd ask!

```
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var range = spreadsheet.getRangeByName(videoIdRangeName);
  var values = range.getValues();
  var videoIds = []

  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    var id = values[i][0];
    videoIds.push(id);
  }
  var stats = YouTube.Videos.list("statistics",{"id": id}).items;

  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    var id = values[i][0];
    if (id) {
      var cell = sheet.setActiveCell(Column.views + (2 + i));
      cell.setValue(stats[i].statistics.viewCount);
      console.log("found stats for: " + id);
    }


  }
```

The above code will pull view data from youtube's api but it only pulls the lifetime view data.

Comment: Unfortunately, in the current stage, it seems that the transition of view count cannot be directly retrieved with the time range by YouTube API. So as one of several workarounds, how about measuring the view count using the time-driven trigger? For example, when you want to check the transition of the view count every 1 week, the script can retrieve the view count by installing the time-driven trigger as 1 week. In this case, this can be achieved by Google Apps Script. If this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: Adding on to Tanaike's comment, which is the right approach, you can add the metrics to the spreadsheet, say, weekly, and then calculate the changes through the weeks to get an idea of its progression.

Comment: Thanks, you two! That was my planned work-around api couldn't pull stats per-month. It's still a heck of a lot faster than doing in manually!